# PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist [JpaRepository]

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA with JpaRepository and I couldn't find an answer to why my entity is detached and I can't save with children entity.

I want to save Recipe but first I need to save Ingredient in another service. Recipe and Ingredient is connected many to many relations by RecipeIngredients object.

```
@Transactional
public RecipeDto updateRecipe(UserPrincipal userPrincipal, String recipeName, RecipeDto recipeDto) {
            Recipe recipeToEdit = recipeRepository.findByName(recipeName).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
            recipeToEdit.setIngredients(recipeIngredientsService.refillRecipeIngredientsList(recipeDto.getIngredients(), recipeToEdit));
}
```

[image: Table relation]

```
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredients {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientsId recipeIngredientsId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("recipeId")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @MapsId("ingredientId")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Ingredient ingredient;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Ingredient {

@Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<RecipeIngredients> recipeIngredients;

    public void addRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredients recipeIngredient) {
        if(recipeIngredients == null) {
            recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        recipeIngredients.add(recipeIngredient);
        recipeIngredient.setIngredient(this);
    }
}
```

Before I want to save **Ingredient** entity I want to check there is exist so I pull it from external service then map It to DTO object. If there is no **Ingredient** I want to save it and get his object, which will be connected children **RecipeIngredients** and this is connected to **Recipe** so when I'm saving recipe it should save me **RecipeIngredient** with it of **Ingredient**.

```
public void refillRecipeIngredientsList(List<RecipeIngredientsDto> recipeIngredientsDtos, Recipe recipe) {
    removeOldIngredientsIfExist(recipe);
    if (recipeIngredientsDtos != null) {
        for (RecipeIngredientsDto recipeIngredientsDto : recipeIngredientsDtos) {
            IngredientDto ingredient = pullSavedIngredient(recipeIngredientsDto);
            RecipeIngredients recipeIngredient = this.recipeIngredientsDtoToEntityMapper.recipeIngredientsToEntity(recipeIngredientsDto, recipe, ingredientDto);
            recipe.addIngredient(recipeIngredient);
            ingredient.addRecipeIngredient(recipeIngredient);
        }
    }
}
```

But in every way I received `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.app.todaysdinner.entity.ingredient.Ingredient`. Do anyone know the answer how to reattach Ingredient entity?

**[EDIT]**

I found out that when I want to update through `Recipe` cascade on `RecipeIngredients` also cascade onto Ingredients that means it invoke PERSISTANCE method even if allowed is only `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}`. But I can't find answer why in one `@Transaction` object is being detached.

Comment: Add @Transactional at the controller method so both different service methods  executed in one transaction

Comment: Yes I have added @Transactional onto updateRecipe method (added to edit)

Comment: You posted the code for `Ingredient`, with the `addRecipeIngredient` method. Then you post the `refillRecipeIngredientsList` method, in which `ingredient` is of type `IngredientDto`, but mysteriously enough, it also has an `addRecipeIngredient` method, taking in an entity as a parameter. If you want us to devote our time studying your problem, could you at least show us the *actual* code of your application?

Comment: By the way, you left out the `recipeIngredientsDtoToEntityMapper.recipeIngredientsToEntity()` method, which seems to be crucial in the context of your problem

Comment: It is also worth adding what happens in `pullSavedIngredient` method and entity `Recipe`.